# Convergent series of fractions

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a}{n}$ guaranteed to converge for any value of a? Or does it simply go to infinity? I'm most interested in a = 1,  but it is also interesting to see whether there is a general case.

Comment: Look up the $p$-series test

Comment: **HINT**: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a}{n}=a\times\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: $a=0$ is the only constant giving convergence. For nonzero $a,$ recall that multiplying by $a$ will not affect divergence or convergence. So really, the only interesting case is $a=1,$ which is the famous harmonic series.

Comment: A multiplicative coefficient has no influence on the convergence/divergence of a series. Your question isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=0$, the series converges.  If $a\not=0$, it diverges.  An elementary way to see the divergence of $\sum{1\over n}$ is to note that

$$\begin{align}
1+{1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over4}+\cdots&=1+{1\over2}+\left({1\over3}+{1\over4} \right)+\left({1\over5}+{1\over6}+{1\over7}+{1\over8} \right)+\cdots\\
&\gt{1\over2}+{1\over2}+\left({1\over4}+{1\over4} \right)+\left({1\over8}+{1\over8}+{1\over8}+{1\over8} \right)+\cdots\\
&={1\over2}+{1\over2}+{1\over2}+{1\over2}+\cdots
\end{align}$$